# Loop 3000 records through SSIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

New to SSIS can someone help in Looping 3000 Records at a time.
I have a table of million records. I want to get 3000 records at a time and load into new table. Next time when i run the "FOR Loop Task" in SSIS, It needs to Loop another 3000 records.

Comment: you dont need to do that, SSIS has batches built in so you can just transfer all of it at once and SSIS control flow will handle the throughput

Comment: In the destination component in the data flow, set max commit size (3000 in your case) and Rows Per Batch (1000000)

Comment: Yeah, best way to do this if it must be done in SSIS, is add a SQL Script task and do all the work there.

Answer (score 0):

The data source inside for loop should be custom SQL like below

```
select Top  3000
*
from SourceTable S
left join DestTable D
on S.primarykey=D.primarykey
where D.primaryKey is NULL
order by indexcolumn
```

Comment: Can you please explain more